# Xamarin Binding a StyleClass

Tags: xamarin

I have a converter which determines the background colour of a Frame.

```
<Frame 
     BackgroundColor="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource ProjectListingBackgroundConverter}}"
```

Works fine.  But the converter has the colour names hard-coded into it.

However in order to support the new Dark Mode's, I need the colour to be based on a StyleClass.  I tried:

```
StyleClass="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource ProjectListingBackgroundConverter}}"
```

And changed the converter to return the correct style class.  But this resulted in:

```
object not set to instance of object
```

I assume you **can't** bind a StyleClass?

Any ideas how I might achieve what I want?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I know, `StyleClass` is not a bindable property.

You could use `Style` to binding the styles.

App.xml:

```
 <Application.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Frame" x:Key="Green">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green">
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```

Page1.xaml:

```
 <ContentPage.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <local:ProjectListingBackgroundConverter x:Key="BackgroundConverter" />
    </ResourceDictionary>

</ContentPage.Resources>

<!--BackgroundColor="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}"-->
<ContentPage.Content>
    <Frame x:Name="frame" Style="{Binding Status,Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}">
        <Label x:Name="label" Text="Page1"></Label>
    </Frame>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Page1.cs:

```
  public string Status { get; set; }
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Status = "Green";
        this.BindingContext = this;
    }
```

Converter:

```
public class ProjectListingBackgroundConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value.ToString()=="Green")
        {
            return (Style)App.Current.Resources[value.ToString()];
        }
        return (Style)App.Current.Resources[value.ToString()];
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```